# How to resolve "SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x3, The system cannot find the path specified"?

Tags: html

I have this img tag, that should display an image. However, it keeps popping up as an 'x' in Chrome, Firefox, Internet Edge, or Explorer. So what can be the problem? do you have check my internet browser settings if there is a compatibility issue.

I tried other images too and they wouldn't work. I would also like to state that my image folder is inside a folder called 'My Website" and then it has a folder called "HTML" which has my index.html page then I have an image folder inside that folder which contains that image.

Also, I have pressed "F12" and pressed "Ctrl" and "Click" on the image location and the actual image appeared on the screen but not the side. I also get this error in the console:

> SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x3, The system cannot find the path specified.

I don't know if this would help narrow down the problem.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>My First Website</title>        
    <meta http-equiv="My website" content="text/html; charset=uft-8"/>
        </head>  
        <body>
        <img src="HTML/flightsiminside.jpg" height="267" width="400"/>
        <div>
        <header>
           <h1>My first website</h1>
            </header>
        </div>
        </body>   
    </html>
```

Comment: from your description it sounds like the url should be `./images/flightwhatever.jpg` replace "images" with whatever your images folder is called and the file name too..

Comment: Wow that's a confusing explanation. I'm not sure where your image actually is, but you have the path wrong.

Comment: check your image path you can type full path and check it or try another image like google logo here https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png